# I can get my cookie session in application > cookies tab in chrome browser but can't use it to login in another sub-domain

Tags: php, session, cookies, subdomain, session-cookies

This is my php block of code for sharing session to subdomain.

```
<?php
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".example.com");
$cookie_name = "hash";
$method = "aes-256-cbc";
$key = 'hashkey';
$iv = 'DEFGHTABCIESPQXO';
$cookie_value = bin2hex(openssl_encrypt($mobile, $method, $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (900 * 30), "/", ".example.com");
?>
```

I want to login with a.example.com and when I open b.example.com it shouldn't ask me to login again. 
I can find the cookie in my another subdomain too, but it is asking me to login again.
Is there anything I should do to access the cookie in another subdomain?

Comment: Are you sure that the condition that shows the login form checks only if the cookie exists? And is the protocol the same for both of attempts? (http:// or https://)

Comment: I tried applying if condition like this:

`if isset($cookies_name){ 
    else if isset($submit{

//code block
 
    }
}`

it didn't worked for me either.

Comment: "$cookies_name" - do you mean $_COOKIE['hash'] ?

Comment: **Yes.**  See. I am new to php I just tried this logic but failed. Is there any solution for this to solve? I mean a block of code that can be used other than mine. If you did tried earlier can you explain how did you do that?